# iOS Highcharts Library - Hiding layout elements & Y Axis precision

Tags: ios, highcharts

I'm working on Line Chart with [iOS Highcharts library](https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-ios).

Here are the codes I used:

```
// Highchart
HIOptions *options = [[HIOptions alloc] init];

// Chart Type
HIChart *chart = [[HIChart alloc] init];
chart.type = @"line";

// Title
HITitle *title = [[HITitle alloc] init];
title.text = @"";

// Legend
HILegend *legend = [[HILegend alloc] init];
legend.enabled = 0;


// X Axis
HIXAxis *xAxis = [[HIXAxis alloc] init];
xAxis.categories = xAxisData;

// Y Axis
HIYAxis *yAxis = [[HIYAxis alloc] init];
yAxis.labels.formatter = @"";

// Line
HILine *line = [[HILine alloc] init];
line.data = yAxisData;

options.chart = chart;
options.title = title;
options.legend.enabled = 0;
options.tooltip.enabled = 0;
options.xAxis = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObject:xAxis];
options.yAxis = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObject:[[HIYAxis alloc] init]];
options.series = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:line, nil];
options.credits.enabled = 0;
options.navigation.buttonOptions.enabled = 0;


self.highchartView.options = options;
[chartArea addSubview:self.highchartView];
```

I got quite a lot problems displaying the data:

[image]

As you can discover from the codes, I try to hide the credits wording, the hamburger menu and the legend, but they are still there (I want to make tooltip disappear as well, but it's still there even I set it disabled). Also, the precision of the Y axis is obviously a problem. How can I set the Y axis precision?

Here are the data used:

```
X: 1980 Y: 0.000000115
X: 1981 Y: 0.000000028
X: 1982 Y: 0.000000038
X: 1983 Y: 0.000000016
X: 1984 Y: 0.000000032
X: 1985 Y: 0.000000038
X: 1986 Y: 0.000000045
X: 1987 Y: 0.000000069
X: 1988 Y: 0.000000045
X: 1989 Y: 0.000000074
X: 1990 Y: 0.000000054
X: 1991 Y: 0.000000058
X: 1992 Y: 0.000000049
X: 1993 Y: 0.000000066
X: 1994 Y: 0.000000065
X: 1995 Y: 0.000000059
X: 1996 Y: 0.000000050
X: 1997 Y: 0.000000048
X: 1998 Y: 0.000000062
X: 1999 Y: 0.000000081
X: 2000 Y: 0.000000079
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to instantiate credits, exporting and toolbar objects, set `enabled` option to 0 or NO and add them to `HIOptions` - this will make credits, toolbar and hamburger disappear.

Regarding to precision, you can use a labels.formatter and return this.value.

```
    yAxis: {
        allowDecimals: true,
      labels: { 
        formatter: function() {
          return this.value;
        }
      }
    },
```

Example:

- http://jsfiddle.net/w6py2jm7/

Comment: Wait. It's on iOS, not JS. You may notice that I have already set the value of `credits` (for example) to `0` (which I guess it stands for disabled). It's weird that the `enabled` property is a `NSNumber`, instead of a `BOOL`.

Comment: In the iOS you can also use formatter for labels: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts-ios/yAxis.labels.formatter

Comment: Can you show us how to use the formatter? The API example is in JS, which is not related.

Comment: According to docs, you need to use JS in this place. It is related with fact, that wrapper transforms the iOS code to JS and functions require to have he rfight references (js).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of 0 / NO

set them as follows:

```
options.credits.enabled = @false;
options.navigation.buttonOptions.enabled = @false;
```

or

```
options.credits.enabled = [NSNumber numberWithInt:0];
options.navigation.buttonOptions.enabled = [NSNumber numberWithInt:0];
```

Sometimes I have better luck with the NSNumber method.

Comment: there's no difference at all.